# Why does this make sense?Java( Years and minutes)

Tags: java

I just want to thank everyone for the great support, I just need some help because I had some help writing some this program so I am a bit confused on whats going on in the back.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuzzLightYear {
    public static void main (String [] args ){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number of minutes Eg: 1000");

        long minutes = input.nextLong();

        long numberOfDays = minutes / 1440L;
        System.out.println("Number of days: " + numberOfDays);
        long numberOfYears = numberOfDays / 365L;
        System.out.println("Number of years "+ numberOfYears);
        long numberOfSeconds = minutes * 60L;


        System.out.println(minutes + " minutes, is approx" +  "\nNumber of days: "
        + numberOfDays % 365 + 
                "\nNumber of years: " + numberOfYears );

        System.out.println(numberOfSeconds + " Seconds");



    }
}
```

Ok the part I do not really understand is inside the `system.out.println` why do we need to take numberOfDays and % 365 why would we want to find remainder of numberOfDays.

I understand that we need to divide minutes by 1440 becuase that is how many minutes is in 24 hours but I don't really understand why we divide numberOfDays by 365 in the middle of the problem, like if we divide lets say 365 by 730 shouldnt we get 2 years?

I just need a bit of explantation because I am some what new at Java so I'm not as quick learning about what goes on behind the scenes.

Thank you for all the support again, and sorry for the poor grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `numberOfDays` is equal to 415.  That's more than a year.

If you want to represent your date in years and days, then you'd have a years component of 1(because there is 1 complete year), and you'd have a days component of 50(because after you subtract that year, you have 50 days left.

`415 % 365` leaves you with the days **component**, which is 50 days.

Comment: Did you meant `365+50 = 415` instead?

Comment: Perhaps another base?!

Answer (score 1):

Example: I type in 1,000,000 minutes. This is 694 days, 10 hours, and 40 minutes.

Without the modulo operator, it would report 1 year and 694 days, which obviously is not true. The % 365 is because there are (approximately) 365 days/year

Comment: Oh that makes sense thank you. so the modulo is to find out the remaining days and make sure it doesnt report false like 694 days and 1 year instead it will report 1 year and like 300 ... days

Answer (score 1):

`numberOfDays % 365` is not division - it is a modulo operation. Basically it will give you the remainder from division by 365. Therefore, if you have 731 days, 731%365 = 1.

You have already calculated `numberOfYears` to be 731/365 = 2. Therefore, combining these 2 will give you 2 years and 1 day which is the same as 731 days.

Comment: So basically your saying that is why I have to use the modular (remainder) symbol in order to find out how many days I have ? like in the sysoutprint you see how i did numberOfDays % 365 was that to find how many days I have remainding in that year? Therefore like you say 731 days is equal to 2 years and 1 day. I get it a bit better that way thank you

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's kind of like writing fractions - (2 + 1/365) years = 2 years (quotient of division) + 1 day (remainder of division).

Answer (score 1):

If you use integer division, say 100 / 40, the quotient is 2 and the remainder is 20.

So, in Java, divide integers using '/', to obtain the integer quotient, and use the remainder-after-integer-division operator '%' to obtain the remainder.